# Поменять местами два элемента односвязного списка

Tags: c++

В односвязном списке нужно найти элемент, удалить его и поменять местами два следующих. С первой частью задания справился, но не могу поменять местами два следующих элемента.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Структура:

```
struct SingleList {
int Data;
SingleList *Next;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пусть два следующих не NULL.

```
// ptr -> a -> b -> c
SingleList *a = ptr->Next;
SingleList *b = a->Next;
ptr->Next = b; // a -> b -> c
               //      ^         
               //  ptr |

a->Next = b->Next;  //        a -> c
                    //             ^
                    //  ptr ->   b |

b->Next = a;        //  ptr -> b -> a -> c
```

Добавьте необходимую логику в случае если имеется NULL значение и проверку на NULL перед обращением к Next.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое!